# move magento db to another server

Tags: magento

I have a Magento website, from the cpanel I created db backup and saved it to my pc, but I don't know how to import it to my new magento website.

P.S: the old hosting is now expired and I have only this db backup.

Comment: Do you have access to PHPMyAdmin or MySQL command-line?

Comment: You can just use PHPMyAdmin Import once you make the new DB or you 'source filename' on MySQL command line after you make and use the said DB.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-commands.html

Comment: it's not working, I received an error

Comment: Error at the line 413: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_text`

Comment: MySQL: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: You would need to drop your entire database and then import the database.  You are attempting to place stuff over existing.  You either need to make a new DB and then import, or drop the existing after backing it up, then import.

Comment: I already created an empty db and received the same error

Comment: Do you know the version of MySQL between your server and your previous?

Comment: current is mysql 5, but i don't know the old

Comment: Can you look at your raw SQL file, and see if it is trying to create a table? If so what is the name?

Answer (score 0):

I've found exporting the Magento database through cpanel/phpmyadmin tends to have more problems with key conflicts than exporting through the command line. But since your hosting is expired we'll have to make do with what you have.

You'll need to edit the sql file inside the .sql.gz file (extract with any zipping program).

Add this line at the start of the sql file

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

And then add

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Then try importing into an empty db again.